# Double subscript error

Tags: subscripts

```
\begin{equation}
f_s = \frac{1}{T} \geq  2 f_m_a_x
\end{equation}
```

I am getting double subscript error. Although I am getting correct format of equation in pdf but in code it is giving this error. can anybody help me in solving that. Thank You

Comment: Do you want to have max as one word ? use f_{max}

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  f_s = \frac{1}{T} \geq  2 f_{\mathrm{max}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Why `\mathit`? The most common usage is `\mathrm`. And braces should be added around the subscript; it works without them, but by chance.

Comment: @egreg, I just used italic version because the OP said the PDF looked like what was wanted. I should add the braces though.

Comment: It's very possible that the model document has the wrong, but unfortunately very common `f_{max}`. Textual subscripts should always be upright.

Comment: @egreg, fair enough. I'll change it!